# simple counter changes color of digit to red(decrease) green(increase) somehow struggle to have zero black

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am just going through some simple js projects and got somehow stuck here.
I have a counter which has two buttons to either in- or decrease the shown value by one.

negative value red - positive value green

zero is supposed to be black

I have already thought about creating another variable outside the scope which keeps track of the count but it didn't quite work either.

thanks for any help

```
const counter = document.getElementById('counter');
const buttonDown = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const buttonUp = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');



buttonDown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(counter.textContent == 0);
  console.log('test')
  if (counter.textContent == 0) {
    counter.style.color = 'black';
  }
  counter.textContent--;
  if (counter.textContent < 0 ) {
    counter.style.color = 'red';
  } 
})

buttonUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  if (counter.textContent == 0) {
    counter.style.color = 'orange';
  }
  counter.textContent++;
  if (counter.textContent > 0 )
  counter.style.color = 'green';


})
```

Comment: Whats the output of your console.logs ?

Comment: false than true...which means the zero isn't recognized as a number but everything below/above is

Comment: here the github files of the project including the solution

Comment: https://github.com/romeojeremiah/Counter-Project

Comment: where did the `orange` come from?!?!?

Comment: It is unclear if counter can become negative.  By the spirit(...) of your code, I guess not.

Comment: Check *numeric* value of `counter` - as suggested in an answer by @Raffobaffo, or by `Number(counter.textContent)` or `Number(counter.value)`.

Comment: On `buttonDown` `click` use `if "numeric value" of counter "is" zero, then set to black, *else* decrease by one and set to red`.

Comment: orange was just for testing purpose....

Comment: I had if else statements before but didn't achieve the desired result....when I am outside the scope of the eventListener the textContent is being recognized as numeric value. Sorry btw, the counter is supposed to become negative which is why I mentioned in the OP that negative numbers are red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand what you need:

```
const counter = document.getElementById('counter');
const buttonDown = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const buttonUp = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');

function updateCounter(change) {
  var counterNumericValue = Number(counter.textContent)+change;
  counter.textContent = counterNumericValue;
  counter.style.color=(counterNumericValue>0)?"green":(counterNumericValue<0):"red":"black";
}

buttonDown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  updateCounter(-1);
});

buttonUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
  updateCounter(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change as follow

```
   if (parseInt(counter.textContent) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code corrected:

```
const counter = document.getElementById('counter');
const buttonDown = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const buttonUp = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');

buttonDown.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var counterNumericValue = Number(counter.textContent);
  if(counterNumericValue == 0)
    counter.style.color = 'black';
  else {
    counterNumericValue--;
    counter.textContent = counterNumericValue;
    counter.style.color = 'red';
  } 
});

buttonUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var counterNumericValue = Number(counter.textContent);
  counterNumericValue++;
  counter.textContent = counterNumericValue;
  counter.style.color = 'green';
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help iAmOren. I pasted your code in my editor but now the down button doesn't go below zero. It basically stops at zero. And positive values are now shown as red when lowering the count. Thanks anyways

Comment: Did you want the counter to go below zero?  If so, remove `if ... else`.
Lowering the count => red - that's what I understood.  Did you mean negative values in red, positive in green and zero in black?  If so: `counter.style.color=(counterNumericValue>0)?"green":(counterNumericValue<0):"red":"black"`.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve. Where exactly do I paste the code snippet in? Sorry for these noob questions...your help is much appreciated. The snippet shows a couple of errors when I paste it into VS code

Comment: @Aaron, I've posted a new answer based on my new understanding - hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks heaps mate. Just replaced the colon before "red" with a question mark and it works like a charm. I haven't used the conditional ternary operator that much so far. Didn't notice it straight away. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, typo...  Great that you've noticed!!!  You could also make `counterNumericValue` a global var - this way you never have to read it - just "write" it (and change color - which you can check).